# Website loses connection after few seconds

Tags: networking, windows-8

I'm using a Windows 8.1 (Update 1) computer for school and I regularly go on their website (located at chamilo.avondschool.be). But every time I go to the website, the page takes a very long to load. Whenever I change the page it takes around 6 seconds for the first request and then everything is quite fast until I do another page change.

Some investigation has led me to believe it is only my computer. Other computers on the network are not having this issue. I also think it is the computer itself, not a specific browser, because Chrome Firefox and IE all have the same issue.
Another thing I discovered (using Sysinternals tcpview), the connection to the IP-address is "claimed" by [system Process] (PID: 0).

Please help me.

Comment: "Please help me" is not a good way to get assistance here. Please read [ask], then [edit] your post to include a specific question for what you would like assistance with. We'd be happy to help, but need the right information to do so.

Comment: Are the same symptoms occurring when visiting other sites as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is completely fixed. The problem consisted of some VirtualBox Network Interfaces which were not used at all. Removing these solved the problem.